# Transform onChange when using register

Tags: react-hook-form

Is it possible to trasnform outgoing values with just `register` and v7 of react-hook-form?

I did this by overwriting the `e` I pass to `onChange` however it never becomes the value I set it. `325`

```
  const { onChange, ...registration } = props.form.register('foo');

  const handleChange = e => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const transformedValue = 325;
    onChange({
      type: e.type,
      target: {
        name: e.target.name,
        type: e.target.type,
        value: transformedValue
      }
    });
  };

return <input {...registration} onChange={handleChange} />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that no `ref` can be initialised by your call to `register` outside the `<input />` element.

For the registration of a `ref` you can either add a [custom register](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#ControlledmixedwithUncontrolledComponents), this would give you the possibility to modify the current value of your `<input />` element after a change via the `setValue` method (which is provided by `useForm`). Or another way would be to [share your ref](https://react-hook-form.com/faqs#Howtosharerefusage) to your `<input />`.

However, I think that `setValueAs` should also work well in your case. This will run the provided function before returning your input value. [Here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) is the relevant section from the docs.

```
<input {...register("foo", { setValueAs: value => `${value} 325` })} />
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Basic (forked)]

Comment: Thank you! setValueAs did the trick. I tried the custom register with setValue and it seems to have worse performance, maybe it's something I did.